# Calling function with property as byref argument causes set method call

Tags: vb.net, properties, function-call, byref

When calling a function with a property as an argument that's declared byref, the property's set method is executed after the function call.

This tosses a compiler error if done in c# if you try to pass a property into a function with `ref`, but in vb.net this goes through. Is this a bug? What's going on?

```
Module Module1

    Private _testProp As Integer
    Property testProp As Integer
        Get
            Return _testProp
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            Console.WriteLine("changed TestProp to " & value.ToString())
            _testProp = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub testFunction(ByRef arg As Integer)
        Console.WriteLine(arg)
    End Sub

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("explicit set to 5 in main")
        testProp = 5
        Console.WriteLine("calling function")
        testFunction(testProp)
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Output:

> explicit set to 5 in main
>   changed TestProp to 5
>   calling function
>   5
>   changed TestProp to 5

Comment: Since it is passed ByRef, the method ~could~ change the original value, but it doesn't actually know if the value was changed; thus it updates the property after the method call to make sure it has the latest value.  Seems like "ByRef by Illusion, and a quirk you just need to be aware of?  I'm just guessing here as I couldn't find any actual documentation on this.  =/

Comment: Because passing a reference type by reference enables the called method to replace the object which calls the setter. The called method "could" change that value possibly it doesn't quite know, so it get's set before actually using it.

Comment: TBH, I would read up on how arguments can be passed [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/passing-arguments-by-value-and-by-reference) and [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/passing-arguments-by-value-and-by-reference), clearly *not a bug*, just a miss-understanding.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like this behavior is documented in the help.  I already checked your two links.

Comment: @Craig somehow my links aren't correct (copy paste error), but in general the ByRef attribute specifies that the value of the parameter will be updated when the method execution finishes...so in this case the property setter is called (create new object) before even being used in the method... Its actually good to do this, what happens when you pass the property and another thread changes this before your method gets this value that you *were expecting*, it's not the same anymore is it; hence why the setter is actually called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing a property to a `ByRef` parameter results in the property being passed by copy-in/copy-out.  The VB language specification states,

> Copy-in copy-back. If the type of the variable being passed to a reference parameter is not compatible with the reference parameter's type, or if a non-variable (e.g. a property) is passed as an argument to a reference parameter, or if the invocation is late-bound, then a temporary variable is allocated and passed to the reference parameter. The value being passed in will be copied into this temporary variable before the method is invoked and will be copied back to the original variable (if there is one and if it's writable) when the method returns.

So this is clearly by design and not a bug.

Comment: It's a rather nasty design. I'd think the set function would be called every time I change the property's reference, instead it's not only called once, but always called once when the function returns. If what you said is true, it would mean that say, a property set that counts the number of times the property has been changed would not update if the property's reference was altered within a function call?

Comment: Absolutely this can cause problems for the unwary.  I recall fixing a bug in software I maintain that was related to this behavior.

Comment: @FalcoGer, the _copy-back_ can be prevented by wrapping the `ByRef` argument in a set of parentheses.  i.e. `MethodName((byrefArgument))`.  See: [How to: Force an Argument to Be Passed by Value (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-force-an-argument-to-be-passed-by-value) or [Passing ReadOnly Properties of Controls ByRef](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/com-interop/troubleshooting-interoperability#vbconinteroperabilitymarshalinganchor11) for more info.

Comment: Where did you find this Craig?

Comment: @Idle_Mind on the VB git in discussion of a related issue.  Link here: https://github.com/dotnet/vblang/issues/169 --- see the last response.  I took the liberty of assuming that the quotation there was accurate.

Comment: @Idle_Mind, prior to VS2017, a copy of the [Visual Basic Language Specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/reference/language-specification/) was included with the installation (i.e.: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VB\Specifications\1033\Visual Basic Language Specification.docx).  Now it is its on GitHub as indicted in the prior link.  The specific quote can be [found on this page](https://github.com/dotnet/vblang/blob/master/spec/type-members.md#methods).